# android load webView in background and don't show gui

Tags: android, user-interface, webview

I added the web view in my Android app. I want to load it in background when my application starts.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, b.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: for this you can visible invisible webview

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the visibility to invisible.

As in load your url into web view but don't show it.

Comment: webview visibility or layout visibility

Comment: webview visibility. You can show something else on the screen. Or you want to load webview while your application is loaded and don't want to show anything in the meanwhile??

Comment: main application load url but dont show GUI while run another activity